# ThreadingTCPServer using SSL completely freezes when a client opens an idle socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, ssl, server

**Problem**: ThreadingTCPServer *with ssl* freezes on certain requests despite it supposedly being multithreaded.

**Explanation**:

I'm trying to create an https server that handles every request on a separate thread, thus even if a user request takes long, the server should not hang.

Here's a simple version of my code with print statements and it initially seems to work:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from socketserver import ThreadingTCPServer
import ssl
import threading
import time


class ChildHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('ID:', threading.get_ident(), '1 - BaseHTTPRequestHandler INIT CALLED')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def do_GET(self):
        print('ID:', threading.get_ident(), '2 - do_GET... working...')
        time.sleep(5)
        print('ID:', threading.get_ident(), '3 - do_get... done...')
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()

    def log_message(self, *args): pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = ThreadingTCPServer(('', 1443), ChildHandler)
    server.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(server.socket, certfile='./fullchain1.pem', keyfile='./privkey1.pem',
                                    server_side=True, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    server.serve_forever()
```

And if I open 2 chrome tabs pointing to the server and connect simultaneously, we can clearly see that it serves both users at the same time. With the following output:

```
ID: 49092 1 - BaseHTTPRequestHandler INIT CALLED
ID: 49092 2 - do_GET... working...
ID: 46236 1 - BaseHTTPRequestHandler INIT CALLED
ID: 46236 2 - do_GET... working...
ID: 49092 3 - do_get... done...
ID: 46236 3 - do_get... done...
```

**However**, if I leave this server open for a couple of hours or overnight it will suddenly hang. After days of testing, I was finally able to reproduce this issue although I don't know how to fix it. The following is a malicious script that I can run on a different computer and it will completely hang/freeze/**wreck** my server.

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('MY PUBLIC IP', 1443))
```

Afterwards my server completely hangs. And all its literally doing is opening a socket and then leaving it there... And there is absolutely no output in the console for my server (so BaseHTTPRequestHandler is not even being initialized).
How is this even possible, a client shouldn't be able to completely hang my threaded server just by connecting to my server and then sending nothing!

**Further Debugging**:

For further analysis, I created the following subclass of the `ThreadingTCPServer` that will print before the steps of initializing the request handler:

```
class AnalyzeVer(ThreadingTCPServer):
    def get_request(self):
        print('ID:', threading.get_ident(), '-2 - GET REQUEST STARTED')
        result = super().get_request()
        print('ID:', threading.get_ident(), '-1 - GET REQUEST ENDED')
        return result

    def verify_request(self, request, client_address):
        print('ID:', threading.get_ident(), '0 - VERIFY REQUEST')
        return super().verify_request(request, client_address)
```

And when I run my malicious script my server completely hangs obviously and I get the following output in my server:

```
ID: 30880 -2 - GET REQUEST STARTED
```

So it definitely freezes inside the get_request.

Additionally: removing ssl certificates seems to make this problem go away but I need those :/

Additionally: setting socket timeout to some value (say 10 seconds) will partially fix this problem but it will also make the server hang until the socket times out (10 second freeze for every time I run the malicious script) :/

Additionally: setting socket timeout to anything less than 3 minutes is not possible since I need to transfer files that could potentially take that long, so hanging the server for >3 minutes every time that malicious script is ran is really bad :/

Additionally: the malicious script needs to be run on a python terminal and must NOT close the terminal. If the malicious script terminal closes then the server goes back to normal (must be related to the socket being open with no data)

**EDIT**: As seen above, the hanging happens in the server function called `get_request`. I found this following in the python source code of file [socketserver.py line 397](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/67e394562d67cbcd0ac8114e5439494e7645b8f5/Lib/socketserver.py#L307) that states

> I assume that selector.select() has returned that the socket is readable before this function was called, so there should be no risk of blocking in get_request().

So, I'm assuming whoever wrote that did not consider a specific situation with ssl that causes `get_request()` to hang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `ssl.wrap_socket` is called in the listener socket already. This will cause the socket `accept` to be immediately followed by a TLS handshake - and only after this is done a the new thread with the `ChildHandler` will be spawned. If the TLS handshake is stalled now new connections can be handled. A TLS handshake is easy to stall: just TCP connect and send nothing.

The solution is to spawn the new thread immediately after the TCP accept and do the TLS handshake in the new thread. This way only the new thread will stall on the unfinished TLS handshake but not the main thread. The server will still be able to accept new connections this way.

Moving the TLS handshake to the newly spawned thread can be done by not doing the `ssl.wrap_socket` on the listener socket, but instead do it on the accepted new connection:

```
class ChildHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('ID:', threading.get_ident(), '1 - BaseHTTPRequestHandler INIT CALLED')
        request = ssl.wrap_socket(request, certfile='./fullchain1.pem', keyfile='./privkey1.pem',
                                    server_side=True, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
        super().__init__(request, *args, **kwargs)

    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = ThreadingTCPServer(('', 1443), ChildHandler)
    # no ssl.wrap_socket(server.socket, ...) here
    server.serve_forever()
```

Note that one still should handle invalid TLS handshake using a timeout or similar in order to not accumulate many stalled threads. It makes sense to have a short socket timeout for the TLS handshake and a longer after that. Just use [socket.settimeout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) with different values before and after the call to `ssl.wrap_socket`.

Comment: Brilliant! BRIALLIANT! I thought I had to make my own custom threaded tcp implementation to create threads before the socket. But this is a much better and cleaner approach. Of course it was the handshake, it was so obvious yet I never thought that I could initiate the handshake in the request handler level. This is so great. Additionally, setting different socket timeouts before/after the handshake sounds exactly like another great idea that I need to do. Thanks a lot!